# ImageView of Image height and width?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable

I am using image view in my app. I use this code for setting the bitmap

```
  setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

and imageview makes my bitmap as drawable and use internally.

```
 public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    // if this is used frequently, may handle bitmaps explicitly
    // to reduce the intermediate drawable object
    setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bm));
}
```

so i can get the drawable width and height, and i can get the imageview height and width,but imageview use `CENTER_FIT ScaleType to set Image in Imageview.

but I want to know the Image height and width  ,starting point,ending point consumes of Image in imageview .
so I can do some operations on the top of the image. is it possible?
`

Comment: You mean you need height and width of a bitmap set to your imageview?

Comment: @Shrey no.the image view will automatically scale your image into imageview.so i want scaled image of height and width

Comment: why don't you try to extend imageview class and get the bitmap after it gets scaled to "CENTER_FIT"?

Comment: @shrey i am using that only is there any method something like this?